# Is Ubuntu compatible with Dell n4050 laptop?

Tags: software-installation, dell, laptop

I have dell n4050 laptop. Do i have to install drivers after ubuntu installation? which version of ubuntu will support my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this official [Ubuntu Hardware certification](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201104-7891/) for your laptop (if that really is your laptop, check the hardware specifics) chances are pretty high for it to work out of the box with the advised Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit.

You can also always try any Ubuntu installation before you actually install it on your computer by booting it and choosing "Try Ubuntu" instead of installing right away. More about live testing Ubuntu can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Answer (score 0):

You can install both available and supported versions Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10.
Ubuntu comes with all suitable drivers already preinstalled - there is not much for you to do.

After the installation open Software & Updates (Additional Drivers) and find what is offered.

In case your notebook came with dedicated AMD graphics card, proprietary fglrx is an option.
Generally the already installed open source radeon drivers work great - so you can take them.

For the Broadcom Wireless Card you have to install the additional drivers to get WiFi to work.